Parse JSON response using array of struct with no leading keys in Go
Normally in Go, I would use the following struct:
type Inner struct {
    Key1 string `json:"Key1"`
    Key2 int32  `json:"Key2"`
}
    
type Outer struct {
    Outer []Outer `json:"Outer"`
}

To Decode the following JSON into:
 {"Outer":[{"Key1" : "Value1", "Key2" : 2}, ...]}

I'm unable to figure out what struct to use for the following JSON:
[{"Key1" : "Value1", "Key2" : 2}, ...]

Due to the fact that I have no JSON key for the outer object.  How do you handle this situation?

Parse a JSON array of objects to a Go slice of structs.
data := []byte(`[{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":2}, {"Key1":"Value3", "Key2":4}]`)

type Inner struct {
    Key1 string `json:"Key1"`
    Key2 int32  `json:"Key2"`
}
var v []Inner // <--- slice of struct

err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for _, e := range v {
    fmt.Println(e)
}

Run it on the PlayGround.
See the Unmarshal for documentation for information on the relationship between JSON values to Go types.
